# What is this "process" called so I can research it?

Tags: php

I want to do some research on this and find out about it, but I have no idea what its called or what to search. Basically what I want to do is use PHP to basically automatically fill out a form on another page. So say it goes to Facebook.com and the login text box is named "username." I would like to know how to press buttons by the name of them and enter text to text boxes by their name. What would this be called? Thanks.

Comment: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-curl-form-post/

Comment: its called, in a lot of cases, breaching the TOC of the site you are submitting to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called screenscraping.

You do it by downloading the raw HTML of a page, then navigating the HTML's structure (usually with a DOM library, PHP has one, see http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php ). To submit a form you need to craft a HTTP POST request, then download the result.

If you're submitting a "known" form then you can omit the first step of downloading the original HTML form as your program already knows what the fields to submit are.

A more sophisticated version of this (done to bypass sites that use client-side scripting to prevent trivial screenscraping) is to host an instance of a web browser component (mshtml.dll/Trident, Gecko or WebKit) and have it to evaluate the page as it would in a normal desktop environment. The screenscraper's code then manipulates the DOM to trigger events such as a button click.

Comment: submitting posts request to remote sites is not *screenscraping*

Comment: Not in itself, but it forms a part of screenscraping: when you need to get to a page hidden by a form. I had the impression that the OP wanted to programatically submit a form in order to automate the retrieval of data from a results page. Am I being naive by not assuming the OP wanted to spam a contact form?

Comment: yes, sounds like he has dodgy motives to me!

Comment: No, I am not spamming ANY form... Thanks for the help.